# What alternative should I use to PickPoint in Section Views?

Tags: c#, .net, revit-api, revit

The issue I am dealing with is that I cannot seem to find an alternative to `PickPoint` for SectionViews.

In the Revit 2019 API, I've been trying to create a small script which draws a `DetailLine` between two points. However, I wish these points to be selected by the user, which `PickPoint` is perfect for. Since I need this to work in Section Views too, I'm at a roadblock though.

The relevant code is given.

```cs
XYZ p1 = uiDoc.Selection.PickPoint();
XYZ p2 = uiDoc.Selection.PickPoint();
DetailLine l = uiDoc.Document.Create.NewDetailCurve(
    uiDoc.Document.ActiveView,
    Line.CreateBound(p1, p2)) as DetailLine;
```

This throws a `Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException` in a Section View, since I don't have a Work Plane.

The part that confuses me is that we can very easily draw a `DetailLine` in Revit itself, but I can't seem to be able to do this in my own `AddIn`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I'll leave my solution here for whoever might need help with it.

Basically, Revit doesn't allow you to pick points without an active Work Plane at all. This is because the coordinate system in Revit is three-dimensional, and when you're picking a point with your mouse you can't go in three dimensions. To make sure everything is precise and right, Revit forces you to have a plane on which you will pick a point.

The work-around is a blatant hack, but it works. You have to create a sketch plane, from which you can create a work plane, in which you select a point, and then after that you delete the work plane. It's dirty, but it works.

Since you're creating and deleting stuff, this requires a `Transaction`.

```cs
XYZ pickPoint;
using (Transaction t = new Transaction(Document))
{
    t.Start("Test Transaction");
    SketchPlane sp = SketchPlane.Create(Document, Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(
        Document.ActiveView.ViewDirection,
        Document.ActiveView.Origin));

    Document.ActiveView.SketchPlane = sp;

    // Finally, we are able to PickPoint()
    pickPoint = Document.Selection.PickPoint();

    // Don't forget to clean up
    Document.Delete(sp.Id);

    t.Commit();
}

// Draw whatever you want with this point now.
```

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Before creating a new sketch plan, you should check that there is not already one (`if (Document.ActiveGraphicalView != null && Document.ActiveGraphicalView.SketchPlane == null)`)